# Migrate Table Data Only from MSSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Been tasked with moving a code first database from MSSQL to MySQL. After a few hours of kung fu, I was able to get the asp.net core project to properly deploy all migrations to mysql. Now I need to migrate the data inside of the existing mssql tables. I saw posts mentioning MySQL Migration Toolkit but that appears to be old. Also attempted to do so with MySQL Workbench and DBLoad's Data Loader but haven't had any luck.

Table structure is pretty simple with incremental integer keys + the usual crap with asp.net core identify framework (GUID). Just need to keep that consistent during the migration. What is the best way to migrate the data now that the table structure is setup in MySQL? Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** Some more details...
I attempted a direct migration of the database from MSSQL to MySQL using MySQL WorkBench and DBLoader. But failed on the ASP.net Identity tables big time plus other issues. .net core api took a huge dump in multiple places so that idea is out.

From that point, I migrated the api controller over to mysql and then had to fix a myriad of issues related to mssql fks being too long and a few other issues.

So at this point, the controller works on mysql. I just need to dump all of the data into MySQL and keep the FKs consistent.

I have had a few thoughts with it such as CSV export>import and/or trying a few other things. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Data Export wizard built-in with SqlServer Management Studio (task -> Export Data)
or use [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-create-a-project-and-basic-package-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017) package to migrate data.

Answer (score 0):

Tried MySQL Workbench, DBLoad from DBLoad.com etc to migrate the data directly and they all failed.

So ended up finding a "solution"...

First off, I modified the ASP.net Core project with:

```
        //services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        //    options.UseSqlServer(
        //        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Then went to Package Manager Console and ran: `update-database`

This created all of the tables in MySQL.

Then opened up Microsoft SQL Management Studio. Right clicked on the database Tasks > Generate Scripts. Saved everything to one file with Advanced option Schema and Data selected.

Then opened the db script in Notepad++ and applied the following edits using Replace with Extended Search Mode enabled:

```
GO -> blank
[dbo]. -> blank
[ -> blank
] -> blank
)\r\n -> );\r\n
\r\n' -> '
DateTime2 -> DATETIME
```

After edits were made in Notepad++, I removed all of the SET, ALTER and CREATE related stuff from the text file and then copied all of the insert lines into MySQL Workbench in **order** to ensure foreign keys were already populated before that table's data was inserted. Thank goodness there were no Stored Procedures to deal with! What a pain in the tucus!

Also on a side note, the app is hosted on Azure. Spent a couple of hours fighting the API not connecting to the database. This was not apparent at first as the app was fake throwing a 404 error to Postman. When I first attempted to wire up the API controllers to the MySQL DB, I entered the database connection string into Azure's App Service Configuration. It didn't work at all even though running the app locally worked fine. Ended up finding another post on this here site mentioning to get rid of the database connection string out of the App Service > Configuration window. Worked like a champ after that. All of the data with its auto incremented keys linked up without issue.

I am very pleased with the results and hope I never have to go through this process again! It is always a nice feeling to know an app now runs on a completely open source infrastructure. Hope this helps someone. Good luck.

Comment: Add a link derver on the microsoft server to mysql . You need the mysql workbench or an mysql odbc driver on the mssql box. After this build scripts to fill the data over linkserver. It's not afast process. If you need something realy fast, there are solutions like informatica, aws dms, apache sqoop and Ssis